# Spring @Value to wire a Resource instance pointing to a JSON file

Tags: java, spring

I've seen very few examples that uses this and was trying to get it to work but unable to:

```
package com.acme.service;

public class SampleServiceTest {

   @Value("classpath:data.json")
   private Resource jsonData;

   @Test
   public void testThis() {
      String json = String.join("\n", Files.readLines(jsonData.getFile(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
   }
}
```

Where my file structure (follows Maven standard) is as follows:

```
data-microservice (top folder)
   -src/test/java/com/acme/service/SampleServiceTest
   -src/test/resources/data.json
```

I've tried several of these but doesn't seem to work:

1. classpath:data.json
2. classpath:/data.json
3. classpath:src/test/resources/data.json
4. classpath:/src/test/resources/data.json

Looking to get help on this please, and if you could also provide a background on correct path (i.e. why that correct path works).

Comment: Either of the first two should work--assuming that you *are* running this in a test and not in an actual launch.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I was being silly and running test without any Spring context. It was a matter of just putting in these annotations on the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public SampleServiceTest {
   //body here
}
```

And the **"classpath:data.json"** works!

Although if someone can explain why the classpath works without specifying the directories (src/test/resources) works, that would really be helpful.

Comment: Through your IDE you can specify in your project which folder should be included in the classpath. Path src/test/resources should be part of the classpath, must IDE sets it by default.